# Get element in a class by element's name attribute

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="true" name="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="true" name="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="true" name="3">
```

Now what I want is that get the checkbox in "check" class which has name:1, or 2 or 3

I tried below but not working

```
var me=1;    // need to save it in a variable
$('.check[name=""+me]').prop("checked",true);    // pay attention in  +me
```

I it should work please let me know.Then i will look why it is not working.Thanks for having time on my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there

```
var me = 1;
$('.check[name="'+me+'"]').prop("checked",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 var me = 1;
 $('.check[name='+me+']').prop("checked",true);
```

or

```
 $('.check[name="1"]').prop("checked",true);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r74gw/13/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".check")
  .filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).attr("name") == "1"; 
  })
  .attr("checked", true);
```